# Pow and mod function optimization

Tags: javascript

I need to create an optimized function to count **Math.pow(a,b) % c;** in Javascript;

 There's no problems while counting small numbers like: 
 `Math.pow(2345,123) % 1234567;`

 But if you try to count:
 `Math.pow(2345678910, 123456789) % 1234567;`
 you'll get incorrect result because of Math.pow() function result that cannot count up "big" numbers;

My solution was:

```
function powMod(base, pow, mod){
    var i, result = 1;
    for ( i = 0; i < pow; i++){
        result *= base;
        result %= mod;
    }
return result;
```

Though it needs a lot of time to be counted;
Is it possible to optimized it somehow or find more rational way to count up **Math.pow(a, b) % c;** for "big" numbers? (I wrote "big" because they are not really bigIntegers);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.6).

```
function expmod( base, exp, mod ){
  if (exp == 0) return 1;
  if (exp % 2 == 0){
    return Math.pow( expmod( base, (exp / 2), mod), 2) % mod;
  }
  else {
    return (base * expmod( base, (exp - 1), mod)) % mod;
  }
}
```

This one should be quicker than first powering and then taking remainder, as it takes remainder every time you multiply, thus making actual numbers stay relatively small.

Comment: This fails when the modulus is large.

Comment: @Doug, oddly, you and I both happened to view this question that is over 6 years old within 1 hour of each other. Regardless, out of curiosity how large are you referring to? Of course, it should be expected that the function will fail on an integer value *n* where `n >= 2^53`, but that is a limitation of the language's standards, not a limitation of this answer itself. So, just to clarify, are you saying this answer will fail for `n >= 2^53` or are you saying it will fail even when the modulus is less than `2^53`?

Comment: I was trying to solve a hackerrank challenge that required use of modulo 10^9+7. When squaring ints, this mod exceeds `Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER))` and the failure happens silently. Hackrrank provides `bignumber.js` but using this lib is kind of a bummer when trying to stay vanilla.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is good so far, but you will want to do http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring also known as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method

The idea is that `x^45` is the same as (expanded into binary) `x^(32+8+4+1)`, which is the same as `x^32 * x^8 * x^4 * x^1`

And you first calculate `x^1`, then `x^2 == (x^1)^2`, then `x^4 == (x^2)^2`, then `x^8 == (x^4)^2`, then...

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the mountgomery reduction in combination with exponentiation which is largely useful for large exponents > 256:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_reduction#Modular_exponentiation

It has also been implemented in this BigInteger Library for RSA-encryption:

http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/

Answer (score 0):

Iterative version

```
function powerMod(base, exp, mod) {
    let result = 1;
    // base = base % mod; // use this if base >= mod
    while (exp > 0) {
        if (exp & 1)  //odd number
            result = (result * base) % mod;
        exp = exp >> 1; //divide by 2
        base = (base * base) % mod;
    }
    return result;
}
```